# Removing non zero cells from pandas dataframe and also removing index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
  Z1  Z2  Z3 Z4
   0   0   A  A
   0   B   0  0
   C   0   C  0
   D   0   D  0
   0   0   E  0
```

I want to remove the cells with the value 0 and make it to look like this:

```
  Z1  Z2  Z3 Z4
  C   B   A  A
  D       C  
          D  
          E
```

Comment: what do you want to replace the zeros with? NaNs? ""?

Comment: No I dont want them at all in the dataframe I want to move up "C" and "D" in column Z1

Comment: You can't remove cells from a dataframe. If a row is present, there must be a value for each column of the dataframe in that row. Can you describe better what you're trying to do?

Comment: My final dataframe I want should be having all the cells with its values.There should be no zero elements in it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only export to strings without indices by [`to_string`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_string.html):

```
print (df.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x[x!='0'].values)).fillna(''))
  Z1 Z2 Z3 Z4
0  C  B  A  A
1  D     C   
2        D   
3        E   

df = df.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x[x!='0'].values)).fillna('').to_string(index=False)
print (df)
Z1 Z2 Z3 Z4
C  B  A  A
D     C   
      D   
      E
```

Comment: Will it be good if I took these into new dataframe.All the non zero elements

Comment: In each Dataframe has to be index, so use `df1 = df.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x[x!='0'].values)).fillna('')`